# ML.NET prediction speed improvement for object detection

Tags: object-detection, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

I've created a ONNX model for Object Detection with Visual Studio and ML Model Builder, using VOTT to define the 4 objects I want to detect.

I'm testing the model as explained in the tutorial, and it works well, result is ok:

```
        var sampleData = new MLModel1.ModelInput()
        {
            ImageSource = @"C:\Data\sample1.jpg",
        };

        //Load model and predict output
        var result = MLModel1.Predict(sampleData);
```

Problem is it takes 5 seconds (10 seconds on first run, 5 on the following ones).
sample.jpg is a 700x400 pixels image, 85kb, the computer is a Intel i7 2.9GHz.

Why it's so slow? Am I doing something wrong or this is the speed I should expect?
Here's the image, the objects to detect are the REF, LOT, the hourglass icon and the factory icon.

Is there any other technique I could use to have a faster detection of these objects?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What version of ML.NET do you have? 1.6 just came out and I believe it has improvements when using images

Comment: I'm using 1.6 thanks